# Julia Jump: Calling Fortran within objective function, Type of variable in ccall?

Tags: fortran, julia

I have a question regarding calling Fortran routines within the objective function of an optimization problem set up using Julia Jump. I have found helpful information in multiple forums on how to call Fortran from Julia in general and managed to write a Julia program that successfully calls my Fortran Code *outside* of any optimization procedure:

```
ffreturn = zeros(Float64,1)
xx = 2.0
yy = 4.2
ccall((:FCN, "C:/Users/.../Subroutine.dll"),Cvoid, (Ref{Float64},Ref{Float64},Ptr{Array{Float64,1}}),xx,yy,ffreturn)
```

where the Fortran code evaluates the Rosenbrock function

```
module objective
  implicit none
  private
  public :: FCN

contains

  subroutine FCN(x,y,fvalue) bind(C,name="FCN")
    use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding, only: c_double
    implicit none

    real(c_double), intent(in) :: x
    real(c_double), intent(in) :: y
    real(c_double), intent(inout) :: fvalue(1)

    fvalue(1) = 100.*(y-x**2)**2 + (x - 1.)**2

   end subroutine FCN

 end module objective
```

What changes now if this Fortran routine is called within a Julia Jump objective function is the type of the two input variables (xx and yy in the example above) on the "Julia side". They are no longer of type *Float64* but of type *Variable*. So far I was unable to find out, what to replace the specifications Ref{Float64} for the input variables in the ccall with to get a working code. (Using Ref{Variable} produces running code, however, the Fortran routine always receives input values of 0 for a and y)

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is Julia's calling convention?  Pass by reference or value?  You may need the Fortran's `VALUE` attribute.

Comment: A search in names(JuMP) with filter(x -> uppercase(string(x)[1]) == 'V', names(JuMP)) does not find any type Variable (there is VariableRef, though, and there are some macros  with similar names).  Where is the typedef for Variable coming from?

Comment: Thank you both for your feedback! @evets: Julia's calling convention is _call by reference_. I tried it with the 'VALUE' attribute, however that didnt do the trick, the result stays the same, calling the Fortran routine outside of a Jump objective function with Ref{Float64} for x and y works, when calling it from within the objective function and Ref{Variable} for x and y, the Fortran routine receives only 0s as input.

Comment: @Bill: I got the type definition from the error message I get when I try to call the Fortran code from within a Jump objective function using Ref{Float64} for x and y: _MethodError: Cannot `convert` an object of type Variable to an object of type Float64_.

Comment: You may need to print the typeof x and y within the Jump optimizer just before calling Fortran within JuMP's optimizer,  to be sure they are really Float64 and not a JuMP optimizer structure.

Comment: @Bill I did that, and it confirmed that x and y are of type *Variable*

Comment: This means that your Fortran routine cannot use them. I would ask on the Discourse forum under JuMP what to do, perhaps.

Comment: I will do that, Thank you!